# JSP Forward sends the request to the forwarder

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a .jsp file that receives a request and checks the request's parameters. Within the same directory as this JSP file, there is error.jsp file that is supposed to do error processing. If the parameters are null I want to forward the request to error.jsp file as in:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
  <head></head>
<body></body>
<% 
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
String procName = request.getParameter("procName");
//param check
if(uid == null || procName == null){ %>
<jsp:forward page="error.jsp"/> 
<% }%>
</html>
```

However, this does not work. After the forward line I have the request re-submitted to the same JSP instead of error.jsp. Eventually, I get a StackOverflowException due to the cycle at the server.

If instead of JSP:forward, I use response.sendRedirect() as in:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
<% 
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
String procName = request.getParameter("procName");

//param check
if(uid == null || procName == null){
response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
}%>
</html>
```

everything works fine. Why does the jsp:forward fail to work? According to [this site](http://www.gulland.com/courses/jsp/actions/forward) and the [API](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm9.html) I have the correct tags in place.

PS.: The JSPs are deployed in a JBoss AS with version 4.0.5 GA.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this logic in a JSP at all, but in a servlet. JSPs are for rendering views, not determining control flow. You'll find it much more predictable if you use the appropriate technology for the problem.

Comment: @skaffman I know; this is not the only thing the JSP is doing. If the correct parameters are in place, there is a form that is being displayed after the checks. I cut the code to make it short.

Comment: That's not the point. Your JSP should not be receiving the request and determining control flow, it should *only* be rendering the form. If the original request is in error, then the *servlet* should be forwarding to `error.jsp`.

Comment: @skaffman noted. This is in place because the .jsp can be accessed via browser and I am trying to detect wrong accesses. Otherwise the sole responsibility of the JSP is to render the form. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of the `StackOverflowError` stacktrace so that we can at least identify where it's repeating. Please also tell if you have any servlets/filters mapped in `web.xml` and if so on which URL patterns and what they are all doing.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for pointing out the filters. I have been able to locate a filter within the web.xml that was causing the erratic behavior. I am trying to remove it from the code base.

Comment: Okay, I have reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the stacktrace of the `StackOverflowError` and pay attention to the repeating pattern. Check if there isn't any custom `Filter` been involved which is repeatedly intercepting on the forwarded request and fix the `Filter`'s code or configuration accordingly so that it isn't doing that anymore. For example, remove `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` from the configuration or set some request attribute which indicates that the `Filter` has already done the job.

Last but not least, you should actually not be using a JSP file as a front controller, but a servlet. For new insights you may find the examples in [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) helpful. It also covers basic validation and error handling.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to secure the JSP by itself, where only [this](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=471953) would have been sufficient. For anybody else that has a similar problem, there is a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291545/how-to-put-jsp-in-web-inf) on StackOverflow to have the security in place.