# Protect Java EE webpage

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

How can I go to the source folder of a project **by the browser URL** in Java web. I want to ask that my project (consists of JSP and Servlets) is running at http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.jsp in Tomcat. If I want to go to the source folder that is **myproject through browser's URL** then how can I go? Simply you can tell that I want to hack this project, by knowing this I can prevent this access and can protect my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you, but if you're using some kind of *Controller* pattern (e.g. using *Struts* or a custom servlet that forwards to a JSP), the recommended way to prevent direct access to your JSP pages is to place them in the `WEB-INF` directory and then forward to these pages from your controller. See here for more details: [How to properly put JSPs in the WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291545/how-to-put-jsp-in-web-inf)

The Servlet 2.3 standard also defines how to prevent direct access in a similar manner (without putting them under `WEB-INF`), which then also requires to forward the request to these pages. For details, see here: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=471953