# Url Mapping For Jsp

Tags: xml, jsp, web-applications, url-mapping

I would like to do a mapping for my web pages. A sort of mapping like Servlet Mapping that i've done in the web.XML, not necessarily the same code or procediment but the same result. In other words my goal is to hide the deployment of my web pages. Is it possible?

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291545/how-to-put-jsp-in-web-inf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it the same way as for servlets. The only difference is that you must use `jsp-file` instead of `servlet-class` to declare your servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>hello.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hi</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is there a way to leave out the servlet? Say all the information you cared about was in just the JSP?

Comment: Your jsp-file should be mentioned with path like `<jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>home page</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/ui/newhtml.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>home page</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ui is a folder in 'Web Pages' which contains newhtml.html file.
while writing it in  we need to give its path so I have given there as /ui/newhtml.html. This solved the issue for mine