# AJAX Call Returning 404 (Spring Boot)

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to make an AJAX call from a JS to a JSP file. The JS uses DHTMLX. But I am unable to make the call. I keep getting 404 error. I can understand that it is mostly an issue of the JSP file not being found. But from I am unable to figure out what the path should be.

I am making the call like:

```
CGSHelper.ajaxHandler("aSystemResults.jsp", getStdRequestText() + "&action=getRouterType");
```

I have the file located here:
[Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuYUy.png)

I have tried different possibilities like putting a /, ./ etc. But nothing works. My JS files is located in static folder under the /src/main/resources/static.

Comment: Download fiddler to monitor your requests and mayhaps receive valuable input to your response/request.

Comment: @Programmer It is not much different from Web Developer provided by Firefox. Or maybe I am not able to make it work the way its supposed to work coz this is the first time I am using Fiddler. I just need to know, the JSP that I am calling should be under the static folder or the WEB-INF jsp folder. I have my application properties set as:
`spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly put JSPs in the WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291545/how-to-properly-put-jsps-in-the-web-inf-folder)

Comment: JSP files under WEB-INF are not publicly accessible so this will not work. See suggestions in the link above.